# Want to create a textField for amount payment with some rules in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a textfield for payment amount and here i want thousand separator and after decimal only two digits allow

I copied code for thousand separator but it does not work if i add any other formator in stringFormat array..

here is my code

```
TextField(
               
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
               controller: controller,
                
                inputFormatters: [
                 
          ThousandsSeparatorInputFormatter(),
                ],
              )
```

and here is code taken from stack overflow answers

```
class ThousandsSeparatorInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  static const separator = ','; // Change this to '.' for other locales

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // Short-circuit if the new value is empty
    if (newValue.text.length == 0) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    }

    // Handle "deletion" of separator character
    String oldValueText = oldValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');
    String newValueText = newValue.text.replaceAll(separator, '');

    if (oldValue.text.endsWith(separator) &&
        oldValue.text.length == newValue.text.length + 1) {
      newValueText = newValueText.substring(0, newValueText.length - 1);
    }

    // Only process if the old value and new value are different
    if (oldValueText != newValueText) {
      int selectionIndex =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.extentOffset;
      final chars = newValueText.split('');

      String newString = '';
      for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((chars.length - 1 - i) % 3 == 0 && i != chars.length - 1)
          newString = separator + newString;
        newString = chars[i] + newString;
      }

      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString.toString(),
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
          offset: newString.length - selectionIndex,
        ),
      );
    }

    // If the new value and old value are the same, just return as-is
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate want you want, i didn't understood fully. I got it till you need thousand separator then..?

Comment: a textfield that shows thousand separator as well as decimal with maximum 2 digits like 5,400.39 and than no more decimal allow ...dont want like 5,400.93.39

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1: Import Required Packages
> Import the necessary packages at the beginning of your Dart file:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

> Step 2: Create `TextEditingController` for `TextField`

```dart
TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

> Step 3: Add Listener to `TextEditingController`

```dart
_controller.addListener(() {
  // Remove commas for proper parsing
  String text = _controller.text.replaceAll(',', '');

  // Set the base format for numbers (e.g., "#,##0")
  String formattableText = '#,##0';

  // Check if there's a decimal point
  if (text.contains(".")) {
    List<String> splitText = text.split(".");
    // Add the decimal portion format (e.g., "#,##0.00")
    formattableText += ".${splitText[1][0]}${splitText[1][1]}";
  }

  // Format the input text using NumberFormat
  String formatted = NumberFormat(formattableText).format(double.parse(text));

  // Update the text field with the formatted value and adjust the cursor position
  if (formatted != _controller.text) {
    _controller.value = _controller.value.copyWith(
      text: formatted,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
        offset: _controller.selection.baseOffset - (_controller.text.length - formatted.length),
      ),
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Does code work ? @imemon

Comment: can u pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter