# failing to set value while using provider's constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

So far everything going well and even completed some basics app but suddenly this question has arrived and spoiled everything...failing to understand the concept behind it...and now i cnt focus more until this is solved...

for explaining i have created simple demo

my question is regarding to this statement

```
final provider=Get.put(AppProvider());
```

and  constructor of AppProvider class

```
AppProvider() {
    _numbers = [];
   print(getNumbers.length); //this is showing zero whenever it is called
  }
```

steps of my activity

1. I am moving first screen to second screeen (here i espected AppProvider constructor is called and its printing zero value of list number..Thats fine

2)adding some random integer to number with FAB (like 4 value added)

3. i. move back to first screen
4. again moving to second screen...as same as before..AppProvider constructor is called and print zero value of list number but screen widget showing all numbers which was added previously....so where are these numbers  stored as i have set [] to number in constructor of provider...

This what i am failing to understand...

Pls Pls do help me to solve..no issue if question is down voted.matter is to solve,

i cant focus more until solved

```
class AppProvider extends GetxController {
  List<int> _numbers = [];

  List<int> get getNumbers {
    return _numbers;
  }

  AppProvider() {
    _numbers = [];
   print(getNumbers.length); //this is showing zero whenever it is called
  }

  void addNumber(int number) {
    _numbers.add(number);
    update();
  }
}
```

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('First Screen'),),
        body: Center(child: TextButton(onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return SecondScreen();
          }));
        }, child: Text('Move to SEcond Screen'),),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  final provider=Get.put(AppProvider());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
        Text(provider.getNumbers.length.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),),
        TextButton(onPressed: (){
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
            return FirstScreen();
          }));
        }, child: Text('Move To First Screen'))
      ],),),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          provider.addNumber(Random().nextInt(1000));
          setState(() {

          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the line `final provider = Get.put(AppProvider());` creates a new instance of `AppProvider()` and stores it in the `provider` variable. However, this approach is not suitable for managing the state across screens.

The problem with creating a new instance of `AppProvider` each time you build the `SecondScreen` widget is that it leads to inconsistent state management. When you move back and forth between screens, you'll create multiple instances of the provider, each with its own state.

Here is a quick solution if you want to fix this problem:

```dart
class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  late final AppProvider provider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Get.delete<AppProvider>();
    provider = Get.put(AppProvider());
  }

  // ... your code ...
}
```

Comment: here are the steps and value of List<int> _numbers (declared inside AppProvider Class.  1: when I switch to second screen first time…… _numbers length should be 0 (bcz of this statement final provider=Get.Put(<AppProvider>)
2. Tapping 5 times FAB, means I am adding 5 number to list  so…._numbers length should be 5
3. Moving back to first screen
4. Moving again to second screen(here final provider=Get.Put(<AppProvider>) statement should set _numbers=[] and so length of _number should be 0
5. But second screen showing length 5..this is why?

Comment: The problem is that `put` injects a new instance of `AppProvider` into the memory, since you will have a new instance in the memory whenever you open the second page it doesn't guarantee that when you use `provider` it is the desired instance of  `AppProvider`.
Actually, this is the main issue with `Get X`, it does a lot of magic under the hood.

Comment: Thanks...will study further.....am i wrong brother askin such question after successfully completed an expense application....dont know how could i finish app when i have such poor basic ....feeling bad

Comment: NW, all of us are learning new things everyday.  :)